# iOS auto layout : button.constraints does not return all constrains

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode5, autolayout

I have set below constraints on a button.

[image]

When I log button's constraints as below :

```
NSLog(@"Button constraints : %@", self.button.constraints);
```

It returns height and width constraints only.

```
(
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb784e20 H:[UIRoundedRectButton:0xb785500(34)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0xb784f50 V:[UIRoundedRectButton:0xb785500(29)]>"
)
```

Any idea why is this so?

**UPDATE :** Doing `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]` displays as shown in below image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the other constraints are on the super view, not the button.

You can print out all the constraints by setting a debug point and typing this in the debugger.

```
po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]
```

Comment: It does not display constraints. I have updated my question to show what it displays. BTW, It says `AMBIGUOUS LAYOUT` for some views whereas neither in storyboard nor in logs it gives any hint that layout is ambiguous.

Comment: Just log your superview constraints

Comment: @Retro Even `self.view.constraints` does not have any constraint on button.

Comment: You can call `constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis` on the ambiguous layout controls.  Like `po [0xb8655d0 constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:0]` 0 gives horizontal, 1 gives vertical to help you debug. I don't think ambiguous layout is in the logs, I don't use storyboards so I can't say.

Comment: Good to know about this new method to debug. BTW, calling this  method returns a width constraint for axis 1 and height constraint for axis 0. I don't see anything wrong in these constraints because button's size is always fixed and never changed.